# Angular load everything on startup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to figure our how I can load everything in the angular app on startup then reference it from cache when it is needed. Basically, I have an app that has around 40+ pages with some text and images on each page. I want to basically have a loading screen at the beginning of the app that loads in everything so once they load they don't need internet anymore. The computers that will be serving this app are slow and often loose internet that is why.

Now angular is a Single page app framework. Would it be enough to just use ng-src for images(I think it caches them).

I'm not sure and no-one seems to want to load everything first most people are looking to load it asynchronously and I can't do that

Comment: Sounds to me like your application should not be web-based if your clients can't maintain a stable connection to the Internet.

Comment: I agree, but it has to be

Comment: @Midevilworm is this brochure-ware?  Do you have any dynamic data needs?  If so, you HAVE to have a stable internet connection of some sort.  I'm confused as to what this is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: I'd say cut and paste those 40+ pages of text/images into a Word document, save it to a network file share, and call it a day.

Comment: Its not really brochure-ware, It's more of a manual for users to see almost like a learning course. And they have a stable internet connection in the beginning usually, but most of the time as soon as it loads they walk away from wifi to review the info. We also are more focused on having no visible loading time between the pages. Thats why we want to load it all upfront

Comment: @Midevilworm it shouldn't take more than 10 minutes to build a demo with some images, cut your internet connection, and see if it works.  I would expect that the images will be cached not because of ngSrc (implying that Angular would be doing the caching) but rather because that is normal browser behavior. HOWEVER: browser's don't like it when your content is suddenly gone.  They may try to recheck for a newer version of the content and that could give you issues.  At the end of the day, your best bet is to either try it, or fully download the site to their machine and just let them run it.